# I downgraded Ubuntu to 32 bits, now have problems reinstalling it

Tags: 20.04, grub2, nvidia, 64-bit, 32-bit

I've had a fully functional Ubuntu 20.04 environment, until I recently installed the [HTK](https://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/docs/inst-nix.shtml) library using [htk-tools_3.4.1-ubuntu14_i386.deb](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Di29AvqoRBEJ4haW2nusPT1wMPkE14B1/view). In the process, everything 64 bits was removed for now obvious reasons and the system was essentially downgraded to 32 bits. Virtually nothing worked. Realizing my mistake, I quickly reinstalled Ubuntu. The installation itself works and is fine, except maybe that it now performs a file system check on every start-up, which it didn't do before. But... I get problems when I install NVIDIA drivers (and I will also need CUDA). I've installed the drivers multiple times (Software center -> Additional drivers, sudo apt install...), both -470 and -495 versions. The driver installation goes without complaints, and right afterward `nvidia-smi` works correctly.

However, when I reboot the computer to take the drivers into effect, something goes wrong. When rebooted, I no longer have access to ethernet (no ethernet options in Settings) and some apps are also gone (same that disappeared in the 32 bit downgrading process). Removing the NVIDIA driver and enabling Nouveau doesn't bring ethernet back. I have reinstalled Ubuntu from scratch multiple times, but it's always the same after rebooting after the NVIDIA driver installation.

I currently suspect that the 32 bit excursion made some modification to GRUB, and that the NVIDIA driver installation somehow activates it, and boots in a 32 bit like state. 
Now I have a working Ubuntu installation (without NVIDIA), and I have installed the [GRUB repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and ran an analysis, but this is a bit above my head. I've pasted the log below, if it helps.

Would it be advisable to let this tool repair GRUB (which options should I use) or repair it some other way? Or do I need to do something more drastic, such as deleting the EFI partition or the whole partition table altogether?
Or is there another, more likely, problem causing these issues?

My drives are: 
nvme0n1 with 3 partitions: 1) FAT32/EFI, 2) swap and 3) etx4 for Ubuntu
nvme1n1 with 1 partition: ext4 for /home
(sdx HDDs for Windows installation and data storage)

I don't necessarily need Windows, so I would be ok if the bootloader was removed, if necessary. Ubuntu is the primary OS, and I do not want to change anything in BIOS, which the repair tools seems to suggest.

Below is the log from the boot repair tool:

```
boot-repair-4ppa161                                              

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99-2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at 
    sector 671999480 of the same hard drive for core.img, but core.img can not 
    be found at this location.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme1n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/BOOT/fbx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

nvme1n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   The OS now in use - Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS CurrentSession on nvme0n1p3
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on sdb2

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: NVIDIACorporation from   NVIDIA Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-46-generic 
[...]
```

EDIT: 
The log of what happened when I "downgraded" Ubuntu is too long to post here, so I have uploaded it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ua0zNFSnu0DOUdPjIqMGfXelHRU0Qr9r/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: If you reinstalled Ubuntu then anything you did before that is irrelevant. It's going to be hard or impossible to answer this question since it is predicated on actions that wouldn't have had an effect on your current installation

Comment: There are no 32-bit kernels for *focal* (20.04) unless you're using *armhf* (ie. non-x86) so your system won't boot if it was *converted* to all32-bit (it was possible with releases up to 19.04, but not 20.04; tools won't allow *all* to be converted).   So your question is unclear in my opinion (esp. if you're talking about x86).  You should specify what you actually did.

Comment: I have updated my original post with what happened when I ran that installation that "downgraded" Ubuntu. 
Perhaps it has nothing to do with my problems with installing NVIDIA drivers, but then why does rebooting after installing the NVIDIA driver suddenly cripple my system? What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: The best time to install the Nvidia driver is during system installation, not after-the-fact. You should check/accept 3rd party proprietary software and download updates while installing

Comment: Your pastebin shows the problem... Your `gdebi htk..` command caused removal of packages & you okay'd that.  The HTK package you added FORCED removal... you need to remove that package (you didn't say where it was from; the link you provided was for compile-from-source which won't do that; but pasted a deb install from unknown source) then you can re-install what the htk package install caused to be removed.  Check the *depends* & requirements of packages before install, & read the effects before giving acceptance of them. I see this as user error (*but assumption here as paste was edited*)

Comment: @Nmath Thanks for this! I will try it during my next reinstall shortly.

Comment: @guiverc It is, of course, a user error. I had a "weak moment"; I made a Timeshift snapshot and thought I would revert my system afterward if I wasn't happy, but that didn't work, for now obvious reasons. Lesson learned. I can't undo those changes now, since I have formatted that partition and reinstalled Ubuntu. That's why I don't understand why installing NVIDIA drivers + rebooting cripples a new fresh installation now. It worked like a charm during the initial installation months ago.

Comment: Again specifics matter.  Ubuntu provides many ISOs for a LTS release (20.04, 20.04.1, 20.04.2, 20.04.3 20.04.4.. Server, Desktop & *flavors* for each) and these can install different kernel software stacks as Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernel stack choices (*excluding the OEM trigger by some installs*)- so months ago you may have used different media to what you used the second time; meaning different kernel stack was installed the second time... ie. not the same install!)  We're limited to what you provide, and you provided no installation specifics for us to comment on.

Comment: Thank you. I realize that my previously working installation had other specifics back when I installed the NVIDIA drivers, but I do not recall which versions were used then. My point was mainly that this is unlikely a hardware issue. I will be happy to provide information about the current specifics for you and others to be able to help - what would be useful (what commands  should I run)?

Comment: What am I supposed to get from that?  I see you're using a HWE kernel on 20.04; so was that your that the kernel stack on your initial install? or was your prior install of months ago using the GA kernel stack? or an OEM stack?  (ie. what was provided by `uname` for the old system? was it the same 5.11 kernel? or another *supported* kernel for 20.04....   My point was you've not said what you're comparing it to; as 20.04 has many options; some *defaults* set by the ISO downloaded & used for install; others at install time (if ISO uses `subiquity` installer allowing selection at install time).

Comment: $ lsb_release -a          
No LSB modules are available.          
Distributor ID: Ubuntu          
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS          
Release: 20.04          
Codename: focal          
          
$ uname -a          
Linux ubuntu 5.11.0-46-generic #51~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 06:51:40 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux          
          
$ uname -r          
5.11.0-46-generic

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the formatting right.

Comment: Thank you. I really don't remember the versions that were in use when I made my initial installation in September 2021. I used an older Live USB (same as now), and ran "sudo apt update" and "sudo apt upgrade" before installing NVIDIA - both then and now. The Ubuntu release back then was probably 20.04.2, and now we're at 20.04.3. So the specifics are clearly different.

Answer (score 1):

After what feels like a thousand re-installs and reboots, I seem to have NVIDIA driver, CUDA and cuDNN installed and working. Several lessons learned... Thank you all for your time and help!

I ended up wiping the GPT of my system & boot SSD, and physically disconnecting an HDD on which I have a Windows installation - and followed Nmath's advice to allow 3rd party proprietary software and download updates while installing.
From there, installing the other packages went smoothly.

Again, thank you.